# How to replace "null" values with 0 in R

Tags: r, null

I have a database which has "null" values for some elements. I wanted to replace these "null" values or even delete rows including "null" values from database but I could not find a way to do so. I used is.na to return these rows but it seems that NA and NULL are two different concepts in r. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: there is also an `?is.null` function in r

Comment: @rawr I already tried it and unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"null" might be coming in the class character, as in "null" is not the same thing as NULL in R, so is.null() will not work if it is treating it as a character sequence.

You should be able to find these values pretty easily in your dataset using a which statement:

```
todelete <- which(dataset == "null", arr.ind=TRUE)[1]  
newdataset <- dataset[-todelete,]
```

Or you can try to give a snapshot of what your dataset looks like, using str(dataset) and we can help diagnose better.